# clickable Button while an animated postion change - How to?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I want to change the postion of an Button with an Animation, but while the Animation the button must be clickable.

How can I do this?

I tried some solutions, but I haven't had any success yet.

```
[UIButton beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIButton setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[UIButton setAnimationBeginsFromCurrentState:YES];
mybutton.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-10, 0); 
// I also tried this:
// mybutton.frame = CGRectMake(300, 209, 57, 34);
[UIButton commitAnimations];
```

Please Help

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try this way, i hope it's work.

myButton.center = CGPointMake(160, 300);